# Jmeter - Regular expression to stop at first match

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to get 2269 from below html response. I use

```
<td>XYZ Market Services \(Sydney\)</td>(?s).*name="addCompany" value="(.+?)"
```

Regular Expression with $1$ template and match number 1. but it returns 2271. Somebody please help me to create a regular expression to get the value 2269.

```
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ Market Services (Sydney)</td>
            <td class="center">
                <form action="/FormBuilder/pages/Folders/add.aspx?group=1424sfksdfsdgdsf243-3Q-w&ajax=true" method="post">
                    <input name="addCompany" value="2269" type="hidden" /><input class="XYZLookAlike" type="button" onclick="fnload(this)" value="Add" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>XYZ Market Services (Melbourne)</td>
            <td class="center">
                <form action="/FormBuilder/pages/Folders/add.aspx?group=1424sfksdfsdgdsf243-3Q-w&ajax=true" method="post">
                    <input name="addCompany" value="2271" type="hidden" /><input class="XYZLookAlike" type="button" onclick="fnload(this)" value="Add" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Thank you...

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - but anyway, just use a lazy quantifier: `.*?`. Also, change `value="(.+?)"` to `value="([^"]*)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse HTML, the best extractor is [CSS/JQuery extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) in terms of Maitainability/easyness/performance is:

[image]

See this regarding performances of extractors:

- http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/
- https://dzone.com/articles/response-data-extractors-comparison

Comment: Thank you.. Its really useful.

Comment: at the 2 downvoters , frankly a comment explaining why you downvote would be very helpful. My answer is OK and tested so I really don't understand those downvotes

Comment: I don't understand why did they down the votes to a simple and quick response... But i appreciate your effort. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), there are way better options.

For example you can use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [XPath queries](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) against the response, here is an example of extracting `value` attribute for `addCompany` input where column text is `XYZ Market Services (Sydney)`

```
//td[text()='XYZ Market Services (Sydney)']/following-sibling::*/form/input[@name='addCompany']/@value
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter XPath Extractor]

More information: [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: @Dmitri, it is strange that you advise using XPath Extractor for HTML ? AFAIK it is the worst in terms of performances and it requires running jtidy before being able to execute XPath so I don't think this is the correct answer.

Comment: If you don't consider this answer a good one there is a ▼ sign next to it, next time could you please use it instead of verbal exercises and let the TS and/or the community decide which option is right.